# Python subprocess: Know when a command has finished

Tags: python-2.7, ffmpeg, pygtk

I need a way to know when ffmpeg has finished its work. Here is my [code](https://bitbucket.org/philipyassin/derusher/src/master/derusher.py?fileviewer=file-view-default):

```
def on_button_clicked(self, button, progress_bar, filename):
  self.execute(progress_bar, filename)
  progress_bar.set_text('Encoding')
  progress_bar.pulse()

def execute(self, progress_bar, filename):

  cmd = ['ffmpeg', '-y',
         '-i', filename,
         '-r', '30',
         '/tmp/test-encode.mkv']

  process = sp.Popen(cmd, stdin=open(os.devnull))

  progress_bar.set_text('Done')
```

The 'Done' never shows up. The job is done, though. I can see in the shell window that ffmpeg is done. How can I get the signal?

Comment: is `stdin=open(os.devnull)` really necessary? ffmpeg doesn't require any kbd input, does it? So there is no real reason to redirect `stdin`. I've had some problems with `Popen` (probably my fault) and I prefer the simpler versions such as `check_output`.

Comment: Yes it does. When executing, ffmpeg listens for the keyboard, specifically "q" to abort the process. Disabling it can't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up doing it:

```
    p = sp.Popen(command, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

    def mycallback(p):
        p.poll()
        if p.returncode is None:
            # Waiting for Godot
            return True
        else:
            # Yay, wait is over!
            return False

    GObject.timeout_add(1000, mycallback, p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to force GTK to process pending events after the set_text :

```
##  force the refresh of the screen
        while gtk.events_pending():
            gtk.main_iteration()
```